# Runas weird functionality with command line

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, runas

I have a `.bat` file I use to launch some programs. Some of them require elevated privileges (i.a. a `devcon`-based does-device-exist check), but some don't. So, I run the `.bat` as administrator, and use the `runas` command to run the others.

```
runas /trustlevel:0x20000 "C:\Folder\foo.exe"
runas /trustlevel:0x20000 "C:\Folder\bar.exe"
```

This works for some programs. However, for some it shows this error message (translated from Finnish by self, may be slightly different in English):

```
ERROR: Can not execute - bar.exe
740: The requested operation requires elevation.
```

The weird part is, if I create this `.bat`:

```
@echo off
start "" "bar.exe"
```

and run it with `runas`, it works like a charm. Their combination

```
runas /trustlevel:0x20000 "start \"\" \"C:\Folder\bar.exe\""
```

won't work, because `start` is not a file. What would cause this?

**Update:** I tried another command, and it worked.

```
runas /trustlevel:0x20000 "cmd /c start \"\" \"C:\Folder\bar.exe\""
```

*But*, what I want to know is **not** how to make it work but *why this happens*.

**Update 2:** As suggested in comments by [and31415](https://superuser.com/users/289138/and31415) this is a difference between `foo.exe` and `bar.exe`. But, there must be a difference between the ways of running them, as their results are different; that difference is what I'm looking for.

**Update 3:** I checked the manifests of the programs using [Resource Editor](http://melander.dk/reseditor/), and here they are. Seems like they have the same execution level (`asInvoker`, which is the lowest user level).

[image: Manifests]

The upper one is `bar.exe` and the lower one is `foo.exe`. (I know, the wrong way around :D)

**Update 4:** Confirmed to also occur with `psexec` from elevated command prompt:

```
psexec -l -i bar.exe
```

gets an error,

```
psexec -l -i cmd /C start "" "bar.exe"
```

works.

Comment: What if you run the batch file through `runas`?

Comment: @and31415 That is exactly what I did. Read the question.

Comment: Considering it only happens with *some* programs, I think the reason why this happens boils down to the application themselves.

Comment: @and31415 Now, while this is of course true, do you have any idea about what would be the difference between the ways to call the applications that causes this?

Comment: This is a pure speculation, but you might want to check through a [resource editor](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) whether any of those programs include a [manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx), and see what the `requestedExecutionLevel` tag value is set to. Additionally you could test if you can reproduce the issue by the program as limited user through [`psexec`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx).

Comment: @and31415 Downloaded a tool and checked, edited post.

Comment: @and31415 Confirmed with `psexec`.